# Magento - Where I can get an example module using for the ImportExport Classes?

Tags: magento, import, export

how can I create a Module to import and export custom datas in Magento using the ImportExport classes.

Where I can find a example module in the community?

All information that I find is of dataflow profil and Magento API but I find a little of importExport classes.

Can I run this classes at Magento API call ?

Comment: When I google `Magento - Where I can get an example module using for the ImportExport Classes?` I see some interesting-looking hits - are they not a usable starting point?

Comment: this is the only link in the first page referer to importExport classes http://www.aschroder.com/2012/09/improving-magento-importexport-module-with-better-file-format-and-google-docs-integration/ also have information but in german. I searching a example similar to examples in the wiki of magento commerce to create custom module.